# Error on upvote

Tags: bug, status-norepro, up-votes

Was trying to upvote an answer just now and got this strange behavior.

[image]

No particular error message, but I wasn't allowed to upvote and it would just pop up a blank message with the (click on this box to dismiss) message.  A couple refreshes and I was able to vote again, but not a very descriptive error message.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot reproduce this error.

I'd guess this was a bad request (maybe a partial response) or a dodge cached bit of javascript.

Comment: My account had logged off when I refreshed, probably a clue, but it was quickly solved by the site autologging me back in.  Probably not a big issue.